# How to call `InteractiveShellEmbed`-based custom excepthook via `jupyter-console --existing`

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

**Main question:** How can I run an embedded IPython shell with a full-featured prompt (`simple_prompt=False`) in the namespace of a frame where an exception occurred in the context of a running IPython kernel of a Jupyter notebook?

**Explanation:**

I have the following usecase (which is almost solved, up to one major flaw):

In Jupyter notebook (python kernel) I run some nested function call `failing_function()`. Deep down in the call stack an exception happens.
I want to debug the situation *on the commandline* with my custom excepthook (`ipydex.ips_excepthook`; it opens an emebedded IPython shell right in the frame where the exception occurs and offers the possibility to move up in the frame stack, which I find more useful than the classical IPython debugger).

I can achieve this with the following steps: Within an ordinary python script:

```py
import sys
from jupyter_console.app import ZMQTerminalIPythonApp

# mimic jupyter-console --existing: attach shell to running kernel
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], "--existing"]
app = ZMQTerminalIPythonApp.instance()
app.initialize(None)
super(ZMQTerminalIPythonApp, app).start()

code = """
import ipydex
import traceback
try:
    failing_function()
except Exception as ex:
    value, tb = traceback._parse_value_tb(ex, traceback._sentinel, traceback._sentinel)
    ipydex.ips_excepthook(type(ex), ex, tb)
"""

# run this code in the context of the running kernel
app.shell.run_cell(code)
```

**Problem:**

This works, but with one flaw: It only offers the `simple_prompt`-mode of the embedded IPython shell. Background: My custom excepthook internally creates an instance of `from IPython.terminal.embed.InteractiveShellEmbed` and calls its mainloop (as intended). This mainloop has two different prompt-modes: default and simple. The default mode has many desired features (colored output, TAB-completion, ...), which I desire but the simple mode does not offer. The mode is determined by this line [IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py#L134](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/43f9010d15eff67ef6a63fd162c86a96ba57c376/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py#L134).

I tried to force the class variable `InteractiveShellEmbed.simple_prompt` to `False` but then I get `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`  (would have been too easy).

I see three possible ways to achieve the desired behavior:

- a) Let `InteractiveShellEmbed` run in default (i.e. not simple) mode inside the running `ZMQTerminalIPythonApp`.
- b) Run `ZMQTerminalIPythonApp.shell.mainloop()` directly in the namespace of the frame where the exception occurs (and offer the possibility to go up and down again in the frame stack).
- c) Temporarily overwrite `sys.excepthook` with my custom `ipydex.ips_excepthook` and just execute `failing_function()` without `try ... except`.

For a): The whole story with the custom excepthook is just my motivation. The problem boils down to achieving that `app.shell.run_cell('IPython.embed(colors="neutral")')` runs in default (not simple) prompt mode.
For b): I dont know whether that is possible because `InteractiveShellEmbed.mainloop` accepts key word args `local_ns` and `module` (global name space), whereas `ZMQTerminalIPythonApp.shell.mainloop` does not.
For c): This works perfectly for normal scripts but not when "injecting" code in a running jupyter kernel, because overwriting `sys.excepthook` does not seem to have an effect.

Derived questions:

1. Which of the directions (a, b, c) is the most promising?
2. What would be a good next step?
3. What other possibilities do I have?